# C# Decimal ToString() moving the decimal place

Tags: c#, tostring

I have the # `508600000` stored as a decimal value. I convert it into a string and then I need to turn it into `0.00000508600000`. I know I could multiply my *decimal* value `0.00000000000001` and get the same answer, but I'd rather do it as a *string*. Is there any formatting in `ToString()` to make this happen?

Comment: No, AFAIK and in any case it will be totally pointless. A multiplication will be a lot faster than a string manipulation

Comment: If you explain why you think that you want to do a string operation, maybe we can think of an appropriate answer to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pointless, but still:

```
string result = "0.00000" + 508600000;
```

Comment: For once, I would prefer `string` instead of `var` since the type may not be *that* obvious

Comment: This would not work if the number is 5. Then, you would want to have 0.00000000000005, so more zeros at the left.

Comment: The question didn't specify anything on this

Comment: thanks! Now I'm wondering, what would the answer be for any # *  0.00000000000001 in string format? I don't want it to be have to have that many 0s in front, since any # * 0.00000000000001 won't always have that many 0s.

Comment: I don't think there is any such string formats. This is fairly an arithmetic operation, not a string based one. Thus, you need to apply math here.

Answer (score -1):

```
decimal x = 508600000;
string z = String.Format("0.00000" + x);
```

You can use String.Format()